# Kafka unable to connect to Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I have just started learning Kafka/Zookeper. Issue I am facing is, when I try to run the console consumer to verify the message for a topic, I get the below error-

```
vagrant@debian-70rc1-x64-vbox4210:~$ $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 192.168.33.10:2181 --topic topic-3
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,666] INFO Verifying properties (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,698] INFO Property group.id is overridden to console-consumer-92151 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,699] INFO Property fetch.message.max.bytes is overridden to 1048576 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,700] INFO Property consumer.timeout.ms is overridden to -1 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,700] INFO Property socket.timeout.ms is overridden to 30000 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,700] INFO Property auto.offset.reset is overridden to largest (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,701] INFO Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 192.168.33.10:2181 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,701] INFO Property socket.receive.buffer.bytes is overridden to 2097152 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,701] INFO Property fetch.wait.max.ms is overridden to 100 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,702] INFO Property auto.commit.enable is overridden to true (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,702] INFO Property refresh.leader.backoff.ms is overridden to 200 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,702] INFO Property auto.commit.interval.ms is overridden to 60000 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,703] INFO Property fetch.min.bytes is overridden to 1 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,734] INFO [console-consumer-92151_debian-70rc1-x64-vbox4210-1424645796729-11446a89], Connecting to zookeeper instance at 192.168.33.10:2181 (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,754] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,755] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3-1203054, built on 11/17/2011 05:47 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,756] INFO Client environment:host.name=debian-70rc1-x64-vbox4210.vagrantup.com (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,756] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_75 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,757] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,757] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,757] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=:/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.0-beta1-src//bin/../core/target/scala-2.8.0/kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0-beta1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.0-beta1-src//bin/../core/target/scala-2.8.0/kafka-assembly-0.8.0-beta1-deps.jar:/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.0-beta1-src//bin/../perf/target/scala-2.8.0/kafka-perf_2.8.0-0.8.0-beta1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.0-beta1-src//bin/../libs/*.jar:/usr/local/kafka/kafka-0.8.0-beta1-src//bin/../kafka*.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,758] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,758] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,758] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,759] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,759] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,759] INFO Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-4-amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,759] INFO Client environment:user.name=vagrant (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,760] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/vagrant (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,760] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/vagrant (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,761] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.33.10:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@234a98fa (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-02-22 22:56:36,773] INFO Opening socket connection to server /192.168.33.10:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2015-02-22 22:56:42,778] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2015-02-22 22:56:46,791] INFO Socket connection established to 192.168.33.10/192.168.33.10:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2015-02-22 22:56:46,801] INFO Session establishment complete on server 192.168.33.10/192.168.33.10:2181, sessionid = 0x14bb3752996000d, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2015-02-22 22:56:46,803] INFO Session: 0x14bb3752996000d closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:880)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:151)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:112)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:123)
        at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.create(ConsumerConnector.scala:89)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:178)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
[2015-02-22 22:56:46,804] INFO EventThread shut down (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

It says-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
```

I verified the topic and it is present. What is going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and here is how I fixed it:

1) Stop all Kafka and Zookeeper processes

`ps -aux | grep zoo`

`ps -aux | grep kafka`

(then proceed to kill all process ids from above jobs)

2) Run zookeeper

`<kafka_dir>/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties`

3) Run kafka server

`<kafka_dir>/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties`

Answer (score 4):

Try -> telnet 192.168.33.10 2181
If the telnet fails, then the issue is due to below reason.

Zookeeper Server NRPE iptables chain does not appear to a have a default accept rule.

Unless you just want your own iptables chain for NRPE, you could use:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 2181 -j ACCEPT
```

This solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follwoing to see if it helps ..
1) Make sure the zookeeper is up and running, try to connect to it using the zkCli client . 
2) append `--from-beginning` at the end of your command to see if you get any diifference in the output , so the command should be changed to :

```
    $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper xxx.xx.xx.xxx:2181 --topic topic-3 --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was already  connected to the host from which I was trying, so it was not able to make any new connection to the host. I had to change the config: [maxClientCnxns](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.8/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_configuration) so that it was able to make more connection to that host. More details [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/51191/understanding-apache-zookeeper-connection-rate-lim.html).